# Resizing width after changing position

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a sliding menu effect by changing the left value of my `main` element. I need it to resize to fill the remaining space created by shifting to the left however. I tried adding `width: 100%` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  The position change behaves as I had hoped but I can't get the element to correctly resize also. Here's what I have so far

```
<div>
    <!-- Nav Here -->
</div>
<main>
    <!-- Content Here -->
</main>
```

```
main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  left: 0;
}

main:hover {
  left: -5rem;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear do you need main to slide in or the nav?

Comment: I have both on page by default and I want the main to slide left to cover the div while expanding to fill the remaining screen space

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few ways of solving this, but rule no. 1 is that `width: 100%` is almost always a bad idea. Most of the time it will not work, while probably messing up something unintended.

On to solutions:

So solution no 1. is probably the simplest one, and looks something like this:

```css
#main {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 200px;
  right: -85px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #50505050;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  z-index: 99;
}

#main:hover {
  right: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="nav">
  <!-- regular old content -->
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <!-- this slides out -->
  <p>slide to the left</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

How it works is that, instead of resizing the sliding menu it has a (semi)-fixed size and starts out at a position that is partly *outside of view*.
hen, once you hover over it, the entire element is moved left, causing it to slide fully into view.

Great thing about this solution is that the sliding menu is completely agnostic of the rest of the page, which makes it easy to maintain. Changing something in `nav` won't break whatever is in `main`<sup>1</sup>.

For a more detailed explenation of this implementation you can take a look at [this example](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/sliding.en.html).

The second implementation is a little trickier, and involves flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: right;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  
  /* not needed when you have content */
  min-height: 250px;
}

#nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: left;
}

#main {
 flex-shrink: 1;
 z-index: 99;
 background: #50505050;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#main:hover {
 flex-grow: 2;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div id="nav">
<!-- regular old content -->
<p>Hello world</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
<!-- This is the sliding part -->
<p>Expands left</p>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this implementation *does* resize, and the menu is more of an expanding, rather than a sliding, one.

A more complete explanation of flexboxes can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) but very briefly, the menu takes up space of 1/3rd of the available space by default, but when hovered on will expand to  2/3rds of the available space instead. You can manipulate this by assigning different `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` values.

Advantages of this method are that it is size independent, flex will do all the calculating for you, so you don't have to worry about manually setting right and size values like with the first solution. I also find this looks a little more modern than ye olde slide menu, but you can make anything look good with enough work of course.

Disadvantages is that flexboxes are the black magic of CSS, and can be difficult to grasp.

Hope either of these help you create what you want, but otherwise there's also plenty other resources and tutorials you can find.

Footnotes:

1: I strongly suggest you switch the ids of `#main` and `#nav` around by the way. `#main` should be where your main content lives, `#nav` is for site navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your second solution is very close to what I'm looking for. The difference is that I basically need to "overgrow" the main content. By default the main should be taking the remaining space after setting the width of the nav and then when I want to hide the menu, it should grow to full screen width, covering the nav.